# C# .NET Core ReadAsStringAsync() throws System.OperationCanceledException

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, kestrel

Im using C#'s `HttpClient.GetAsync()` method to make an API request from an endpoint URL, the API returns a JSON string and then I retrieve the result using `HttpContent.ReadAsStringAsync()` method. It works successfully. But when I hit `CTRL+C` on the `dotnet run` running process, unexpectedly it throws an `Unhandled exception. System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.`, is there any way to get rid of this?

My fully controller method:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var result = await _httpClient.GetAsync("projects/7/issues?scope=all&per_page=100&page=1");
    if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var content = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        Issue[] issues = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Issue[]>(content);
        return Json(issues);
    }

    return NoContent();
}
```

Exception:

```
Unhandled exception. System.OperationCanceledException: The operation was canceled.
   at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowOperationCanceledException()
   at System.Threading.CancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.WaitForShutdownAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.Run(IHost host)
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what you expect to happen when you unexpectedly cancel operation with Ctrl+C?

Comment: @alexei-levenkov I expect the program will gracefully shutdown without throwing any exception when hitting `Ctrl+C`.

Comment: in order for the program to shut down gracefully, it *has* to throw that exception, to give you a chance to clean up after yourself. If the program just stopped, your code may leave things in an inconsistent state. Just `catch` the exception.

Comment: @john-wu I've catched the exception, but then it throws until the `CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();`, so do I need to catch my `CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();` too?

Comment: When you shutdown your process you also kill the Http request. You have to handle Cancelation if you want to quit gracefully.

Comment: @kiksen I did, but `CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();` keep throwing an exception even though the controller has catched the exception. I added the cancellationtoken in `_httpClient.GetAsync(..., ct)` and `ReadAsStringAsync()` is a non cancellable method.